# <video> Tag in Safari - Safari cannot play video with codec x265

Tags: html, reactjs, video, safari

I'm using React Nextjs to play video

```
<video
    src="/video_x265.mp4"
    autoPlay
    muted
    loop
    playsInline>
</video>
```

The video cannot be played in Safari (version 16.2 (16614.3.7.1.7, 16614)).

After a while of working around, I realized that Safari cannot play video that has codec x265. I fixed it by callback source video.

```
<video
    className="object-cover w-full h-[60vh] sm:h-fit"
    autoPlay
    muted
    loop
    playsInline>
    <source
        src="/video_x265.mp4"
        type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1"
    />
    <source
        src="/video_x264.mp4"
        type="video/mp4; codecs=hvc1"
    />
</video>
```

It's worked fine but I don't understand why. When working around I have seen this article [Browser Compatibility Of HEVC/H.265 Video Format On Safari 13](https://www.lambdatest.com/web-technologies/hevc-support-on-safari-13) and it told that x265 video is full support in Safari version 16.

I use [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) to encode videos. Here is information of the videos.

**video_x264.mp4**

```
Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Duration: 00:01:26.15, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2046 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1907 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 131 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

**video_x265.mp4**

```
 Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Duration: 00:01:26.15, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 929 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 789 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx265
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 131 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

I wonder how the issue above happened.

Comment: **(1)** Actually H264 is the **avc1** and H265 is the **hvc1** (some players want **hevc**, instead of the "hvc1", to be used as the codec name). Test `codecs=hevc` in Safari. **(2)** Maybe your H265 is not correct (for Safari) in some way. Check with [Media Info online](https://mediaarea.net/MediaInfoOnline) then paste its text results into your question. This way maybe someone can check for any possible problem with your H265 file.

Comment: I had tested with `codecs=hevc` and Safari has not accepted. I have to use `codecs=hvc1` due to [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/http_live_streaming_hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices#2969487:~:text=to%20Level%207.-,1.10.,-You%20SHOULD%20use). I used ffmpeg to encode video, I will update the video info to question.

Comment: PS: Why H265? Is it for a smaller file size or maybe you need it for transparency effect? If used for transparency then you need an MOV file, not an MP4 one.

Comment: Yes, it's for reducing file size, and performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

I found this

> Safari on iOS supports low-complexity AAC audio, MP3 audio, AIF audio, WAVE audio, and baseline profile MPEG-4 video. Safari on the desktop (Mac OS X and Windows) supports all media supported by the installed version of QuickTime, including any installed third-party codecs.

in [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH2-SW10:%7E:text=Safari%20on%20iOS%20supports%20low%2Dcomplexity%20AAC%20audio%2C%20MP3%20audio%2C%20AIF%20audio%2C%20WAVE%20audio%2C%20and%20baseline%20profile%20MPEG%2D4%20video.%20Safari%20on%20the%20desktop%20(Mac%20OS%20X%20and%20Windows)%20supports%20all%20media%20supported%20by%20the%20installed%20version%20of%20QuickTime%2C%20including%20any%20installed%20third%2Dparty%20codecs.)

For short, Safari iOS supports low-complexity media and Safari MacOS supports media depending on QuickTime Player.

The Mac device on the above issue is being in macOS Big Sur, Version 11.7.1. Which have QuickTime Player still has issues itself.

> QuickTime Player refuses to play some H.265/HEVC flavors (as well as Final Cut Pro 10.6). Currently macOS 11-12 Big Sur and Monterey are more forgiving but they still has the following issues with "Codec ID" and "Chroma subsampling" options.

[Quicktime discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253813055#:%7E:text=QuickTime%20Player%20refuses%20to%20play%20some%20H.265/HEVC%20flavors%20(as%20well%20as%20Final%20Cut%20Pro%2010.6).%20Currently%20macOS%2011%2D12%20Big%20Sur%20and%20Monterey%20are%20more%20forgiving%20but%20they%20still%20has%20the%20following%20issues%20with%20%22Codec%20ID%22%20and%20%22Chroma%20subsampling%22%20options.)

So we need to add fallback source to low-complexity media to support cases.